# How to animate akin to :enter and :leave when object reference changes

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Here is some working code:

**Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tt9vjd?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)='swap()'>Swap object</button>
<div @div *ngIf='object'>{{ object.data }}</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: antiquewhite;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from "@angular/animations";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { interval } from "rxjs";
import { first } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  animations: [
    trigger("div", [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({ transform: "scale(0)" }),
        animate("250ms 0ms ease-out", style({ transform: "scale(1)" }))
      ]),
      transition(":leave", [
        style({ transform: "scale(1)" }),
        animate("250ms 0ms ease-in", style({ transform: "scale(0)" }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  object: any = { data: "DIV_1" };

  swap() {
    this.object = null;
    interval(0)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.object = { data: "DIV_2" };
      });

    // DESIRED CODE INSTEAD OF THE ABOVE
    // this.object = { data: "DIV_2" };
  }
}
```

The issue with this code is that an intermediary `null` state had to be introduced. Thus I am mixing presentation code with logic in order "to make it work". This is violating good encapsulation practices and adds unnecessary complexity to the code.

**How can the same results be achieved using code exclusively in the `animations` property in the decorator?**

**requirements**

- Detect a change in the object reference.
- React to the object reference change akin to how `:enter` and `:leave` work; First animate `DIV_1` out, then animate `DIV_2` in.
- Encapsulate anything regarding the animation in the `animations` code. So the swap function should be: `swap(){this.object = { data: "DIV_2" };}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I spent a bit to solve, but I found a possible solution that can help you. You should create a custom directive to use instead of the classic `ngIf`.

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  TemplateRef,
  ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngIfAnimation]'
})
export class NgIfAnimationDirective {
  private value: any;
  private hasView = false;

  constructor(
    private view: ViewContainerRef,
    private tmpl: TemplateRef<any>
  ) { }

  @Input() set ngIfAnimation(val: any) {
    if (!this.hasView) {
      this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.tmpl);
      this.hasView = true;
    } else if (val !== this.value) {
      this.view.clear();
      this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.tmpl);
      this.value = val;
    }
  }
}
```

Quickly: we clear the current view, instantiate an embedded view and inserts it into the div each time there's a change.
About your component your animations will be like this (you can change them of course):

```
animations: [
    trigger('div', [
      state('void', style({ transform: 'scale(0)' })),
      state('*', style({transform: 'scale(1)' })),
      transition('void => *', [animate('0.2s 0.2s ease-in')]),
      transition('* => void', [animate('0.2s ease-in')])
    ])
  ],
```

And your template:

```
<div [@div] *ngIfAnimation="object">{{ object.data }}</div>
```

Remember to remove your `*ngIf` because you can't have multiple template bindings on one element.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hc8snt?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this doesn't behave as `:enter` and `:leave`. Notice that the content is changed to `DIV_2` instantly in your solution. I want the object to disappear, then change value, then reappear. Your solution applied in a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bv82db?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Updated ;) Thanks. It was tricky but funny. I hope it helps

Comment: That did the trick :) I played around with it and also posted what I ended up with.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share what I ended up with. The solution is mostly inspired by Francesco Lisandro's answer.

- A structural directive is created
- The directive takes an object with 2 properties

  - **data**: The object of which the reference changes
  - **leaveTransitionDuration**: A duration that delays the insertion of an empty state
- The directive inserts a void state after the old object and before the new object is created. The void state is inserted after the leaveTransitionDuration.
- The directive does not apply the leaveTransitionDuration when the reference changes from a falsy value to an object. So the regular `:enter` animation is not delayed.

**app.component.html**

```
<div @div *ngIfAnimation="{data: object, leaveTransitionDuration: 2000}">{{ object.data }}</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  animations: [
    trigger("div", [
      transition(":enter", [
        style({ transform: "scale(0)" }),
        animate("500ms 0s ease-in", style({ transform: "scale(1)" }))
      ]),
      transition(":leave", [
        style({ transform: "scale(1)" }),
        animate("2s ease-in", style({ transform: "scale(0)" }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  object: any = { data: "DIV_1" };

  swap() {
    this.object = { data: "DIV_2" };
  }
}
```

**ngIfAnimation.diretive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { interval } from "rxjs";
import { first } from "rxjs/operators";

@Directive({
  selector: "[ngIfAnimation]"
})
export class NgIfAnimationDirective {
  constructor(private view: ViewContainerRef, private tmpl: TemplateRef<any>) {}
  private old_data = null;
  private leaveTransitionDuration: number;

  @Input() set ngIfAnimation(object: {
    data: any;
    leaveTransitionDuration: number;
  }) {
    this.leaveTransitionDuration = object.leaveTransitionDuration;
    this.view.clear();
    if (object.data) this.add_new_view();
    this.old_data = object.data;
  }

  private get delay(): number {
    return this.old_data ? this.leaveTransitionDuration : 0;
  }
  private add_new_view(): void {
    interval(this.delay) // timeout until `:leave` animation is ran
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.tmpl);
      });
  }
}
```

Check out the Stackblitz for a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t7ea53?file=src/app/ngIfAnimation.directive.ts

Note: Make sure the leaveTransitionDuration equals the duration of the :leave transition.